# How to develop and test Laravel package in isolation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 application that I've built a couple of custom packages inside of (I follow [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5) tutorial). These packages have no dependencies that didn't already exist in the root Laravel app.

My first question is, if I needed to add a dependency to the package that wasn't already in the root app, how would it get pulled into the root app? Running `composer update` or `composer install` from the root application does not pull them in. I understand that once I publish to GitHub and later pull the package into my app with Composer, that it's dependencies will pull in...but how do I do it while developing?

My next question is, how do I go about creating automated tests for this package? None of the tutorials I've found address this. Should the package be in it's own instance of Laravel with the tests inside of the `tests` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull in dependencies for your own package, you will need to navigate to your **package root** (not your application root) and run the `composer update` and `composer install` commands from there. That should create a vendor directory local to your package which will contain all dependencies declared in your package's composer.json.

The same goes for testing - you can create a tests directory local to your package inside the larger Laravel app and run your tests from the package root. Just make sure to include your testing dependencies inside your package's composer.json.